# Laravel store value from for-each loop and passed it as array

Tags: php, laravel

I have two for-each loop inside my create view [Subject_id, Lead_id], I want to store the for-each value into my database using array approach, and I couldn't make it work can anyone amend my codes or point me to a proper way thanks.

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $input = $request->all();
    $items = array(['Subject_id','Lead_id']);
    foreach($input as $inputs) {
        $items[] = $inputs;
    }
    $scores = new Score();
    $scores->Subject_id=$items['Subject_id'];
    $scores->Lead_id=$items['Lead_id'];
    $scores->save();
    dd($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('scores.create')->with('notif', 'Success.');
}
```

**this is the message:**[image]

**create view**

```
@foreach ($leads as $lead)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $lead->student_name }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Lead_id[]"  value="{{ $lead->id }}"></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
@foreach($subjects as $subject)
 <label >
    <input type="checkbox" name="Subject_id[]" value="{{ $subject->id }}">
    {{ $subject->subject_name }}
 </label>
 @endforeach
```

DD Result:[image]

Comment: Can you dd() your $items array after the foreach loop and post it? I have a feeling your $items array isn't associative and/or doesn't have the Subject_id key set.

Comment: i have updated the question, DD is working fine

Comment: I think he meant `dd($items)`

Comment: yeah i use dd($items ) its working fine

Comment: Are you want to save array in 1 field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->all();

  $leads = $data['Lead_id'];

  $subject_ids = $data['Subject_id'];

  //insert using foreach loop
  foreach($leads as $key => $input) {
    $scores = new Score();
    $scores->Subject_id = isset($leads[$key]) ? $leads[$key] : ''; //add a default value here
    $scores->Lead_id = isset($subject_ids[$key]) ? $subject_ids[$key] : ''; //add a default value here
    $scores->save();
  }


  //insert using array at once
  $rows = [];
  foreach($leads as $key => $input) {
    array_push($rows, [
      'Subject_id' => isset($leads[$key]) ? $leads[$key] : '', //add a default value here
      'Lead_id' => isset($subject_ids[$key]) ? $subject_ids[$key] : '' //add a default value here
    ]);
  }
  Score::insert($rows);

  return redirect()->route('scores.create')->with('notif', 'Success.');
}
```

Comment: this code work but i can only save 1 value at a time ..is it possible to make it array

Comment: Thank you bro it works, but there is a bit problem it will only save 1=1 value  example student1=[subject1]  if i try to save student1=[subject1,subject2,subject3] it doesn't work but thanks man ill just have to figure this out i really appreciate, you're answer  is the only one working at the moment hehe

Comment: anytime bro. :)
if you wanna store array in table use json_encode(array()). store the encoded value as a string in a column. the use json_decode(string) to again convert it into an array.

Comment: you really help me a lot bro.. thank you so much i wish i could repay your'e goodness and buy u a beer hehe..

Comment: glad to hear that it helped. it feels good after helping someone don't worry about repaying :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time creating an instance of model in foreach loop in not an efficient way. You can do something like this

```
   foreach($input as $inputs) {
     $dataArray[] = [
    'Subject_id' => $inputs['Subject_id'],
    'Lead_id' => $inputs['Lead_id'],
    ];    
    }
DB::table('Score')->insert($dataArray);
```

You can manipulate the data as you want.

with this code i have this[image]

Comment: Don't expect us to write code for you. We can only give you hints/help to come close to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Update your blade

```
    @foreach ($leads as $lead)
    {{ $lead->student_name }}
        @foreach($subjects as $subject)
          <input type="checkbox" name="Subject_id[$lead->id][]" value="{{ $subject->id }}">
          {{ $subject->subject_name }}
        @endforeach
   @endforeach
```

This as your controller

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    $subjects = $request->get('Subject_id');

       foreach($subjects as $key=>$oneLeadOptions) {

           foreach($oneLeadOptions as $option){
                  $scores = new Score();
                  $scores->Subject_id  = $option;
                  $scores->Lead_id = $key;
                  $scores->save();

           }
       }
    //To to other redirects logic here
    }
```

try this

Comment: this code works but wrongly saving data. it won't follow  the array assign to it example: lead_id[1,2,3,4,5] with subject_id[1]

Comment: Are you trying to see which students chooses how many subjects ?
Student A = {Subject 1, subject 2}
Student b={Subject 1. Subject 2, Subject 3}
Student 3 ={Subject 3}

is this what you want to achieve??

Comment: yes for example student 1 [subject1,subject2,subject3] is being assigned